# Please (re?) burninate the [apache] tag

Tags: support, tags

The [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag seems to have risen from the dead and is attracting new questions - I think it may have gotten missed in the burnination requests from [Apache tags - a bit of a mess?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2120/apache-tags-a-bit-of-a-mess) .

(Per the conversation on that thread, [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) is better off split into [apache1](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache1) , [apache2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache2), and possibly future version-specific tags as needed so we can give version-specific help)

Comment: Can there be no questions relating to Apache that are not versions specific? What about things like .htaccess?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - there is a [tag:htaccess] for those questions. Although I now see that the apache tag is empty, so it will be thrown into the lions den in a month I believe.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: We've emptied the apache tag at least 3 times now but it keeps getting resurrected, usually by migrations from SO.  Can you (temporarily) synonym it to apache2 please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we can consider this "completed" with the synonym Apache -> Apache2